# what is the best data structure in this case?

Tags: c++, data-structures

what is the best data structure in this case? I am using c++. yes I am a newbie.

```
Function getValues
Inputs:
    ID // string
    StatType // enum
Output:
    value // double
```

There is a bunch of data which can be organized as a two dimensional array. The function should check the ID and the stat Type and return the appropriate value.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you could use a `std::map< std::string, map<StatType, double> >` or a `map< StatType, map<string, double> >`. My guess is you have more IDs than StatTypes so the latter would be more appropriate.

Comment: if you posted it as answer then I could mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a specification for a function, not a data structure. The function declaration would look something like this:

```
enum enumtype { ... };

double getValues(std::string ID, enumtype StatType);
```